# Samba Share directory outside user directory

Tags: networking, windows-7-x64, ubuntu-14.04, samba

I set up a machine with Ubuntu 14.4.1 yesterday and I am trying to use it as remote storage for a project I am working on remotely with a few people. I know nothing about hosting servers, so I am attempting to avoid the issue entirely by just treating it like a local area network using [Hamachi](https://secure.logmein.com/products/hamachi/).

The Ubuntu machine has 2 hard drives - a boot drive on which Linux is installed and a larger data drive. I am attempting to share a directory on the data drive via samba so that it can be accessed via Hamachi by windows 7 machines.

I am able to see the directories that I have shared, but when I try to enter them, I get a permission denied error. When I share a directory within my /home/user/ directory, it works fine. Is there any way that I can share a directory on my data drive?

Perhaps I could make a symbolic link from my user directory to the data drive? Would that actually work? I am not familiar.

Comment: @down-voter - down-vote if you think it's warranted, but maybe also leave a comment to say why??  What is the file system of the data drive? If it is NTFS, you can't change the permissions, which will be the issue. Otherwise, what are the permissions to the shared directory?

Comment: @asimovwasright: Thank you. The drive was indeed NTFS. I reformatted it and it works properly now.

Comment: You're welcome, I have posted it as the answer, it would be great if you could accept it, so I get the rep :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is NTFS, you can't change the permissions, which will be the issue.